# search & replace wordpress video shortcode with plain URL using regular expressions

Tags: regex, wordpress

i am transferring a friend's wordpress.com blog to a self-hosted install on my server. problem is, he has many videos embedded in his blog using a shortcode plugin that is not necessary on wordpress 3 (you need only to paste the plain URL to embed videos from YouTube, Vimeo, etc;

I've found a Search Regex plugin that will search & replace using regular expressions, but am unfamiliar with regex myself. how might i catch the url in a shortcode such as [youtube="URL"] and replace it with just the URL?

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

-Jenny

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to go from "`[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaNH56Vpg-A]`" to `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaNH56Vpg-A`?

This works if there's a white space between different URLs.

```
find: \[youtube=(\S*)\]
replace with: $1
```

It's difficult to replace every different service at once since it seems that their short codes are different. For Vimeo this would work. It allows a random number of white space between "vimeo" and URL. And it again needs the white space after closing "]".

```
find: \[vimeo\s+(\S*)\]
replace with: $1
```

Maybe theres more robust way to write the expression. (Which validates the correct syntax.) This one's pretty straightforward thought.

The actual regex syntax depend on the language used. Hope this helps.